# Is the term "baby kitten" / "baby puppy" superfluous?

Tags: terminology, taxonomy

If "kitten" is a juvenile domestic cat, and "puppy" is a juvenile dog, are "baby kitten" or "baby puppy" superfluous or just extremely specific?

Comment: "Awww it's a baby baby!" hmmmmmm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This all depends on context of course, but, generally speaking, the terms *baby puppy* and *baby kitten* are neither superfluous nor redundant.  The term *puppy* can be used until a canine becomes full-grown, which can take around a year.  If someone told me they had *baby puppies* or *baby kittens* for sale, then I'd assume they meant very young animals, maybe only a month or two old; if the animals were more like four or five months old, I'd expect the qualifier *baby* to be dropped.

[image]

Comment: Depending on the breed, a dog might not be fully grown physically until it is between two and four years old. I've seen plenty of one-year-old dogs that have clearly been juvenile in build.

Comment: Aww. Should I upvote, simply because of the cute picture....Oh, I already did.

Answer (score 7):

Such apparent superfluity serves to emphasise the youthful nature of the animal in question.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it could be said that it was a [tautology](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tautology).

> **tautology** noun : Needless or meaningless repetition in close succession of an idea, statement, or word

But I would say the repetition is useful to emphasise the point that the puppy or kitten was a particularly young one.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @BarrieEngland's response, I'd say that "baby kitten" will often be used to further heighten the cuteness factor of the fuzzy furball thus described. "Kitten" is cute. "Baby" is cute. "Baby kitten"? Double cute!